# how to apply texure painting

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I know I'm very novice and this may sound stupid but I went to paint on a model and the paint went all over the place instead of staying in the intended target zone , does the paint have to be applied just to the uv maps  to control
where it goes on the model? I was trying to apply it directly to the 3D model
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1x0dU_Zq0e7DUl4-bw_QxF-rxygQr5OyL

Comment: If a UV map is properly set up and has no problems, There should be no issues painting directly on the model.  Make sure your UV map does not have any bugs and that it has been unwrapped correctly. I would recommend this tutorial if you are confused https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scPSP_U858k but there's lots of good tutorials out there!

Answer (score 3):

Each model has to have UVs that correspond to the location of pixels in the texture image to be mapped to it. If the UV map referenced in the texture image mapping is incorrect, then you will see paint strokes apply in odd places. Also happens when multiple faces in the UV editor are overlapping instead of being placed evenly and not on top of each other.